# ExpressJs Compatibility with NodeJs Version

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to find to see if expressjs 4 can support Nodejs 10.15.3 ( Lts) version. Is there any compatibility matrix that i can look into before deciding versions to choose?

Comment: No luck from History or release notes of express4 https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/History.md#4164--2018-10-10

Comment: If big projects like ExpressJS require a new / the newest nodejs-version, they often write it in their README.md on GitHub or on their website.

Answer (score 5):

If you check out [express/package.json](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/package.json) you can see that express needs node v0.10.0 or newer.

So yes, Express.js v4 is supporting Node.js v10.15.3.